can we use .setJournalMode(JournalMode.TRUNCATE) in android application
i am developing an android mobile application using kotlin and room database for backup i am copying database file and unable to copy -wal file due to that some data is getting lost so can we use
.setJournalMode(JournalMode.TRUNCATE)
which deletes the -wal file in database and transaction are directly written in database file.
is it safe to use this will there be any data loss
NOTE: this application has only single user app is similar to todo application
is it safe to use this will there be any data loss


is it safe to use this will there be any data loss

Yes it is safe and there will be no loss of data (unless a rollback is performed).
In Journal mode, the journal file, is a log of the changes made to the actual database, it is only used to change the actual database if undertaking a rollback.
